# Should I use different HDD for Cassandra commit log and data?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I started learning Apache Cassandra. In the `conf/cassandra.yaml` I noticed the `commitlog` setting's comment as following:

`commit log.  when running on magnetic HDD, this should be a
separate spindle than the data directories.
If not set, the default directory is $CASSANDRA_HOME/data/commitlog.`

Does that mean I should store the `commitlog` in different HDD than the `data`?
If yes, what's the reason behind this? And what will happen if I don't comply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a recommendation from the days of spinning-disk.  Due to its log-based storage engine, Cassandra is very dependent on disk I/O.  So it was recommended to have your commit log and data directories on separate disks to avoid a potential bottleneck (latency) due to heavy disk activity.

If you are using solid state drives (SSDs, and with Cassandra you really *should* be) then you don't need to worry about this.

NOTE: This is also why using a NAS or SAN with Cassandra is considered to be an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sadly we're stuck with spinning-disk and I have no influence to manage the HDD settings in the server. Could you recommend other alternatives that doesn't have this issue?

Comment: @RezaKasyauqi Unfortunately, no.  The only way to avoid this issue is to use two physical spinning disks, or a single solid state disk.